# How can I multiply selected elements of a Numpy 2D array by corresponding elements of a 1D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given the numpy arrays `a` of shape `(m,n)`, `b` of shape `(n,)`, and `mask` of the same shape as `a`, how can I multiply the elements of `a` selected by 'mask' by the corresponding elements of 'b'? This works:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> a = np.array([[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1]])
>>> mask = np.array([[0,1,0,1],[1,0,1,0]])
>>> b=np.array([2,3,4,5])
>>> 
>>> a=np.select([mask==0, mask==1], [a, a*b])
>>> print(a)
[[1 3 1 5]
 [2 1 4 1]]
```

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Just curious, did you find any other way?

Comment: No, apart from yours. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

This can be another way, but not sure if more elegant than the method you already have!

```py
a = a * (1 - mask) + a * mask * b
```